# ServletDispatcher cannot be cast to Javax.servlet.Servlet exception in my spring project

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, spring-mvc

While starting tomcat server I am getting an exception

```
SEVERE: Servlet /MavenWeb threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
cannot be cast to javax.servlet.Servlet
```

I am using spring3 but there is jar spring2-5-6 in my lib folder, I removed it from pom.xml but still appears in lib folder - though I am not sure if that is an issue. I am using Eclipse IDE. Thanks!!

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.Draft-6</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
      <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.1-b01</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webflow</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.6</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Comment: In my case, i removed javax.servlet entry from pom.xml and rather added the tomcat library in my classpath.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You shouldn't be using multiple versions of Spring JARs in one project, but this is not the issue.

The problem is most likely caused by servlet API classes loaded by two different class-loaders. Probably you have `servlet*.jar` or some other container-specific JARs in your WAR. Remove them by setting their `<scope>` to `provided` in `pom.xml`.

Comment: I just have javax.servlet-api for servlet in my pom.xml. rest all are org.springframework's artifacts for spring-webmvc, spring-webflow, spring-tx, spring-web, spring-beans and hibernate-annotations. I posted dependacies from my pom.xml above. thankks.

Comment: @Manth: as I said, just change the scope of `javax.servlet-api` to `provided`. Did it help?

Comment: Nurkiewiczit: didn't work. I did change the javax.servlet-api to provided as you said. After compiling i still see the javax.servlet-api-3.1-b01.jar in my target/web-inf/lib folder.

Comment: Care to explain as to why not use multiple versions of spring jars? 
I agree that it is a very good idea to prevent such situations but if you want to use websockets and spring security you must use spring4 and the spring security package uses spring 3.2

Comment: In my case I had to make my tomcat-api scope provided

Comment: I had added `<artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>` dependency to my POM to prevent a bunch of warnings in Eclipse, but I forgot to specify the scope. When I changed it to `<scope>provided</scope>`, the error at runtime went away. Thanks!

Comment: In a weird way, I deleted the javax.servlet-api dependency and worked. I don't understand, because in other computer works with it as 'provided'.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it wasn't a problem with the libraries. I was changing a Standard Servlet to be implemented with Spring, so I followed [these instructions](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/251636/How-to-inject-Spring-beans-into-Servlets?fid=1650916&df=90&mpp=50&noise=3&prof=True&sort=Position&view=None&spc=None&fr=3), that I paraphrase here just in case the page goes down later:

1. Implement `org.springframework.web.HttpRequestHandler` instead of extending javax.Servlet

   `public class MyServlet implements HttpRequestHandler {`
2. Created the bean in the applicationContext.xml (I did it in the dispatcher-servlet.xml)

   `<bean id="MyServlet" class="com.package.to.MyServlet"/>`
3. Specify the servlet in the **Web.xml**, changing the old class (**com.package.to.MyServlet**) to Spring **HttpRequestHandlerServlet**.

   `<servlet>
       <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.context.support.HttpRequestHandlerServlet</servlet-class>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>/MyServlet</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>`

I had to do an additional step to avoid a FileNotFoundException about applicationContext.xml doing the following in the **web.xml**

`<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>`