# Maven project not working on Tomcat 7

Tags: maven, tomcat

I'm trying to run a Maven project on Tomcat 7, but it doesn't seem to work. When I enter from command prompt `mvn clean tomcat7:run`, I get this error:

```
    SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:
 Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].Stand
ardContext[/hitech-store]]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:252)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:111)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.ja
va:1123)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java
:785)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.
java:1559)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.
java:1549)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [St
andardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/hitech-store]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.web.SpringServletCo
ntainerInitializer cannot be cast to javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.getServletContainerInitiali
zer(ContextConfig.java:1657)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processServletContainerInit
ializers(ContextConfig.java:1565)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.jav
a:1273)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfi
g.java:878)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfi
g.java:369)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(Lifecycl
eSupport.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBa
se.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContex
t.java:5173)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 7 more

mag 20, 2013 8:05:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:
 Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:252)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:111)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.ja
va:1123)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.
java:302)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardServic
e.java:443)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.
java:732)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:335)
        at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.run.AbstractRunMojo.startConta
iner(AbstractRunMojo.java:1018)
        at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.run.AbstractRunMojo.execute(Ab
stractRunMojo.java:478)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(Default
BuildPluginManager.java:101)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:209)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProje
ct(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProje
ct(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBu
ild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(Lifecycl
eStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Laun
cher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.jav
a:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(La
uncher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:
352)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [St
andardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.
java:1559)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.
java:1549)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed duri
ng start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.ja
va:1131)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java
:785)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 7 more

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 11.658s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon May 20 20:05:22 CEST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 19M/175M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.0:
run (default-cli) on project hitech-store: Could not start Tomcat: Failed to sta
rt component [StandardServer[-1]]: Failed to start component [StandardService[To
mcat]]: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat]]: A child container fa
iled during start -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionE
xception
```

I have tried everything, including trying to run the project on other computers. Out of 4 computers, it runs on 2 but not on the other 2. do you think it's a problem of Maven or Tomcat?

Comment: Try `mvn -U clean package tomcat7:run`

Comment: Duplicated of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15328363/springservletcontainerinitializer-cannot-be-cast-to-javax-servlet-servletcontain

Comment: I tried, but it's giving me the same error..

Comment: @fmodos I'm not sure if I understood you, but I added this dependency that I took from that project you said :
`<dependency>
   <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
   <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.20100224</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>`
but it still gives me the same error..

Comment: It can be network problem. Check if you can reach localhost from localhost (for example `ping localhost`). Or if the port is not occupied by other process (8080 or other you chose).

Comment: @ajozwik The localhost is reachable..

Comment: @StefanoDiVito what is the spring framework version that your are using?

Comment: @fmodos In the pom.xml, I have version 3.1.4.RELEASE

Comment: ok, please check this website http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc/3.1.4.RELEASE, it shows the maven dependency for this spring version, and the servlet-api is a different one: <dependency>
 <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
 <artifactId>tomcat-servlet-api</artifactId>
 <version>7.0.40</version>
</dependency>

Answer (score 7):

It is actually looking for the right version, I solved it by using below dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Hope this helps!
PS - use the right version, I am using the latest one, remove any other servlet related dependencies and keep just this one.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered exactly the same problem,finally solved.because I set up the operating system environment variables "Path", where a point to my locally installed tomcat, delete this one solved.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem:

```
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.servlet.JerseyServletContainerInitializer cannot be cast to javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer
```

I solved it by adding the following depencency to my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
   <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
   <version>2.5</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Your problem is different:

```
org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer cannot be cast to javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer
```

But this may also be a dependency issue. You "simply" have to find you which dependency is missing.