# mvn tomcat7:run command thrown SEVERE: A child container failed during start

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, tomcat7

I create Maven-based Java web application into Eclipse and I have inserted Apache maven tomcat plugin into pom.xml. When I enter command `mvn tomcat7:run`always through below error:

Here is my `pom.xml`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <name>JavaWebAppDemo Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <artifactId>JavaWebAppDemo</artifactId>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <finalName>JavaWebAppDemo</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <url>http://localhost:9191/manager/text</url>
                    <server>localhost</server>
                    <port>8181</port>
                    <path>/JavaWebAppDemo</path>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>

        <!-- Java Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Java Mongo Java Driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Java Jakson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Log4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jersey Client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jersey Server -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jersey MultiPart -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jersey Core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jersey JSON -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jersey Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jersey Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

and error:

```
    SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].Stand
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:800)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardCon
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer cannot be cast to javax.servlet.Servl
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.getServletContainerInitializer(ContextConfig.java:1670)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.getServletContainerInitializers(ContextConfig.java:1652)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processServletContainerInitializers(ContextConfig.java:1562)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1270)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:878)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:376)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5322)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 6 more

Mar 28, 2015 7:35:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].Stand
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:302)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:732)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:341)
        at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.run.AbstractRunMojo.startContainer(AbstractRunMojo.java:1238)
        at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.run.AbstractRunMojo.execute(AbstractRunMojo.java:592)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:347)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:154)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:582)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:800)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 6 more

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 01:09 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-03-28T19:35:15+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 21M/52M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:run (default-cli) on project JavaWebAppDemo: Could not s
Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat]]: A child container failed during start -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:run (def
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:347)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:154)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:582)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Could not start Tomcat
        at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.run.AbstractRunMojo.execute(AbstractRunMojo.java:600)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[-1]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:341)
        at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.run.AbstractRunMojo.startContainer(AbstractRunMojo.java:1238)
        at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.run.AbstractRunMojo.execute(AbstractRunMojo.java:592)
        ... 21 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Tomcat]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:732)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 24 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 26 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:302)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 28 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
E:\Java\JAVA\JAVA_2015\Java_Program_Demo\Maven Project\JavaWebAppDemo>
```

this is my web.xml file

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
 version="3.0">
 <display-name>Java Web App Demo</display-name>
 <welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>
 <context-param>
  <param-name>firstName</param-name>
  <param-value>Maulik</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
   <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
   <param-value>com.example.rest.jersey</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
   <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
   <param-value>true</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

```js
Apr 01, 2015 11:55:06 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8181"]
Apr 01, 2015 11:55:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Tomcat
Apr 01, 2015 11:55:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
Apr 01, 2015 11:55:07 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/JavaWebAppDemo]]
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:800)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/JavaWebAppDemo]]
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
 ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.servlet.JerseyServletContainerInitializer cannot be cast to javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.getServletContainerInitializer(ContextConfig.java:1670)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.getServletContainerInitializers(ContextConfig.java:1652)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processServletContainerInitializers(ContextConfig.java:1562)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1270)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:878)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:376)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5322)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
 ... 6 more

Apr 01, 2015 11:55:07 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:302)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:732)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:341)
 at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.run.AbstractRunMojo.startContainer(AbstractRunMojo.java:1238)
 at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.run.AbstractRunMojo.execute(AbstractRunMojo.java:592)
 at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
 at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
 at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
 at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
 at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
 at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
 at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
 at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
 at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
 at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:800)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
 ... 6 more
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7801155/how-to-run-tomcat-7-using-maven-2-tomcat-plugin will probably help you

Comment: Please show us your web.xml: The line "Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer cannot be cast to javax.servlet.Servl" in your stack trace looks strange. Maybe the Spring web context load is not correctly configured.

Comment: @gclaussn   check web.xml in question. and that tell me what is exactly problem .... thank you..

Comment: Well, this worked here with a simple jersey example. Try remove `jersey-spring` from your `pom.xml` if you is not using spring.

Comment: maybe helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16657455/maven-project-not-working-on-tomcat-7/17963569

Comment: Briuno César is right, you don't using Spring at all and the exception I mentioned is Spring related. So just remove the jersey-spring dependency - maybe there is some classpath scanning, which causes that problem. But it should be solved, if no more Spring dependencies are involved.

Comment: @gclaussn                                                                                                                      I also remove jersey-spring dependency.. then also error comes. check again in question i print output.  you can also check my whole demo project https://github.com/javadeveloper1993/JavaWebAppDemo using this link.         thank you.

Comment: Like mentioned in my answer - it works. Did you run it from an IDE or from commandline - if you run the demo project from IDE, please try to run it from commandline. You could also try to clean the Maven project and/or delete your local repository. Moreover check your JDK and your IDE version. Looks very strange...

Comment: @gclaussn i also try for run into command line  but same error display .i have install maven 3.2.3 and java 1.8.0 can using this configuration it' is possible to run project?

Comment: @gclaussn I also create new repository same problem occur.

Answer (score 1):

Your project works "out-of-the-box" in Eclipse and on commandline. I'm running on Windows7, Eclipse Indigo, jdk1.7.0_45, Maven 3.0.4

Here the log I receive, when I invoke "tomcat7:run":

```text
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building JavaWebAppDemo Maven Webapp 1.0.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:run (default-cli) @ JavaWebAppDemo >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ JavaWebAppDemo ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 5 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ JavaWebAppDemo ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:run (default-cli) @ JavaWebAppDemo <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:run (default-cli) @ JavaWebAppDemo ---
[INFO] Running war on http://localhost:8181/JavaWebAppDemo
[INFO] Using existing Tomcat server configuration at C:\Users\gclaussnitzer1\Downloads\JavaWebAppDemo-master\JavaWebAppDemo-master\target\tomcat
[INFO] create webapp with contextPath: /JavaWebAppDemo
Apr 02, 2015 3:38:59 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
Information: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8181"]
Apr 02, 2015 3:38:59 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
Information: Starting service Tomcat
Apr 02, 2015 3:38:59 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
Information: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
Servlet Context Initilize With Path :/JavaWebAppDemo
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> MongoDb Information >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
Host Name : localhost
>>>>>>>>>>     Servlet Context Attribute Listner Demo  : Add  >>>>>>>>>>>>>>

    ServletContext attribute added::{host,localhost}

port : 27017
>>>>>>>>>>     Servlet Context Attribute Listner Demo  : Add  >>>>>>>>>>>>>>

    ServletContext attribute added::{port,27017}

DatabaseNames : [ide, local, admin]
>>>>>>>>>>     Servlet Context Attribute Listner Demo  : Add  >>>>>>>>>>>>>>

    ServletContext attribute added::{DatabaseNames,[ide, local, admin]}

MongoDb Conection Created Sucessfully...!!!

Apr 02, 2015 3:39:02 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig init
Information: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
  com.example.rest.jersey
Apr 02, 2015 3:39:02 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig logClasses
Information: Root resource classes found:
  class com.example.rest.jersey.QueryParameterJerseyDemo
  class com.example.rest.jersey.FormParameterJerseyDemo
  class com.example.rest.jersey.FileDownloadJerseyDemo
  class com.example.rest.jersey.PathParameterJerseyDemo
  class com.example.rest.jersey.MatrixParameterJerseyDemo
  class com.example.rest.jersey.FileUploadJerseyDemo
  class com.example.rest.jersey.SimpleHelloWorld
  class com.example.rest.jersey.JsonJerseyDemo
Apr 02, 2015 3:39:02 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig init
Information: No provider classes found.
Apr 02, 2015 3:39:02 PM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
Information: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.19 02/11/2015 03:25 AM'
>>>>>>>>>>     Servlet Context Attribute Listner Demo  : Add  >>>>>>>>>>>>>>

    ServletContext attribute added::{org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache,org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache@1fbbc6da}

Apr 02, 2015 3:39:02 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
Information: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8181"]
```

Here a screenshot from the demo landing page:
[image]

I also checked, if the demos are working - they do.