# Why manually maven clean, install and run the server works, but maven clean install tomcat7:run give A child container failed during start?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat, tomcat7

Extenal tools configuration:

location: 
C:\Users\IMT 02\eclipse\jee-mars\eclipse\apache-maven-3.3.3\bin\mvn.cmd

working: 
${workspace_loc:/SpringRestCrud}

arguments:
clean install tomcat7:run

tool log:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.beingjavaguys.sample:SpringRestCrud:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin is missing. @ line 21, column 12
[WARNING] The expression ${pom.artifactId} is deprecated. Please use ${project.artifactId} instead.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building SpringRestCrud Maven Webapp 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ SpringRestCrud ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Users\IMT 02\git\rest\SpringRestCrud\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ SpringRestCrud ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ SpringRestCrud ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 56 source files to C:\Users\IMT 02\git\rest\SpringRestCrud\target\classes
[WARNING] /C:/Users/IMT 02/git/rest/SpringRestCrud/src/main/java/com/beingjavaguys/dao/ControleDAOImpl.java: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
[WARNING] /C:/Users/IMT 02/git/rest/SpringRestCrud/src/main/java/com/beingjavaguys/dao/ControleDAOImpl.java: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ SpringRestCrud ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ SpringRestCrud ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 7 source files to C:\Users\IMT 02\git\rest\SpringRestCrud\target\test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ SpringRestCrud ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: C:\Users\IMT 02\git\rest\SpringRestCrud\target\surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running com.avenuecode.ProductRCTest
In Unit test
Tests run: 8, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.052 sec

Results :

Tests run: 8, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.2:war (default-war) @ SpringRestCrud ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [SpringRestCrud] in [C:\Users\IMT 02\git\rest\SpringRestCrud\target\SpringRestCrud]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [C:\Users\IMT 02\git\rest\SpringRestCrud\src\main\webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [1680 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: C:\Users\IMT 02\git\rest\SpringRestCrud\target\SpringRestCrud.war
[INFO] WEB-INF\web.xml already added, skipping
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ SpringRestCrud ---
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\IMT 02\git\rest\SpringRestCrud\target\SpringRestCrud.war to C:\Users\IMT 02\.m2\repository\com\beingjavaguys\sample\SpringRestCrud\1.0-SNAPSHOT\SpringRestCrud-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\IMT 02\git\rest\SpringRestCrud\pom.xml to C:\Users\IMT 02\.m2\repository\com\beingjavaguys\sample\SpringRestCrud\1.0-SNAPSHOT\SpringRestCrud-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.1:run (default-cli) > process-classes @ SpringRestCrud >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ SpringRestCrud ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ SpringRestCrud ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.1:run (default-cli) < process-classes @ SpringRestCrud <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.1:run (default-cli) @ SpringRestCrud ---
[INFO] Running war on http://localhost:8080/
[INFO] Creating Tomcat server configuration at C:\Users\IMT 02\git\rest\SpringRestCrud\target\tomcat
[INFO] create webapp with contextPath: 
dez 01, 2016 8:38:17 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMAÇÕES: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
dez 01, 2016 8:38:17 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFORMAÇÕES: Starting service Tomcat
dez 01, 2016 8:38:17 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFORMAÇÕES: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.37
dez 01, 2016 8:38:17 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
GRAVE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:800)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer cannot be cast to javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.getServletContainerInitializer(ContextConfig.java:1661)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processServletContainerInitializers(ContextConfig.java:1569)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1277)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:878)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:369)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5179)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more

dez 01, 2016 8:38:17 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
GRAVE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:302)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:732)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:335)
    at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.run.AbstractRunMojo.startContainer(AbstractRunMojo.java:1091)
    at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.run.AbstractRunMojo.execute(AbstractRunMojo.java:512)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:800)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 14.510 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-12-01T08:38:17-02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 27M/161M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.1:run (default-cli) on project SpringRestCrud: Could not start Tomcat: Failed to start component [StandardServer[-1]]: Failed to start component [StandardService[Tomcat]]: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat]]: A child container failed during start -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

clean log:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.beingjavaguys.sample:SpringRestCrud:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin is missing. @ line 21, column 12
[WARNING] The expression ${pom.artifactId} is deprecated. Please use ${project.artifactId} instead.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building SpringRestCrud Maven Webapp 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ SpringRestCrud ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Users\IMT 02\git\rest\SpringRestCrud\target
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.746 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-12-01T09:03:05-02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/153M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: What version of spring are you using in your project ?

Comment: <properties>
  <spring.version>4.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
  <hibernate.version>4.3.5.Final</hibernate.version>
  <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
  <jdk.version>1.7</jdk.version>
  <org.apache.tomcat.version>7.0.0</org.apache.tomcat.version>
  <context.path>SpringRestCrud</context.path>
 </properties>

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15328363/springservletcontainerinitializer-cannot-be-cast-to-javax-servlet-servletcontain