# Spring boot application works in STS but fails to start with java -jar

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

The applicaton starts and works fine when running from STS(spring tool suite) but when I try to run it using java -jar, I am getting exception.

What am I doing wrong? And if it is working fine in STS, also, when I deploy this .war on tomcat, then also it runs fine; why its not working with java -jar? Any suggestions?

Following is complete stacktrace:

```
2018-09-02 17:32:27.069  INFO 3348 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.23
2018-09-02 17:32:28.087 ERROR 3348 --- [cat-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase   : A child container failed during start

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_161]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_161]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:939) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_161]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_161]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_161]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_161]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
        ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [Pipeline[StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5117) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
        ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.authenticator.NonLoginAuthenticator[]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.startInternal(StandardPipeline.java:182) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
        ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getVirtualServerName()Ljava/lang/String;
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.startInternal(AuthenticatorBase.java:1141) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
        ... 10 common frames omitted

2018-09-02 17:32:28.090 ERROR 3348 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase   : A child container failed during start

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:939) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:367) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:99) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.<init>(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:84) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:554) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:179) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:164) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:134) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537) [spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.9.RELEASE]
        at com.amit.youtube.YoutubeServiceApplication.main(YoutubeServiceApplication.java:10) [classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [youtubeservice-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [youtubeservice-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [youtubeservice-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.WarLauncher.main(WarLauncher.java:59) [youtubeservice-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:948) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
        ... 6 common frames omitted

2018-09-02 17:32:28.093  WARN 3348 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
2018-09-02 17:32:28.109  INFO 3348 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-09-02 17:32:28.117 ERROR 3348 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:137) ~[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.9.RELEASE]
        at com.amit.youtube.YoutubeServiceApplication.main(YoutubeServiceApplication.java:10) [classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [youtubeservice-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [youtubeservice-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [youtubeservice-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.WarLauncher.main(WarLauncher.java:59) [youtubeservice-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:123) ~[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.<init>(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:84) ~[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:554) ~[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:179) ~[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:164) ~[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:134) ~[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.9.RELEASE]
        ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[-1]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:367) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:99) ~[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.9.RELEASE]
        ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Tomcat]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
        ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
        ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:948) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
        ... 27 common frames omitted
```

And following is my pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.xyz</groupId>
    <artifactId>youtubeservice</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>YoutubeService</name>
    <description>YoutubeService</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
          <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
          <version>1.24.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
          <artifactId>google-api-services-youtube</artifactId>
          <version>v3-rev205-1.24.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
          <artifactId>google-oauth-client-jetty</artifactId>
          <version>1.24.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

The section [Create an Executable JAR with Maven](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-an-executable-jar-with-maven) in the [Spring Boot Reference Guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/) explains this quite well. Mainly you have to use the [Spring Boot Maven Plugin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.4.RELEASE/maven-plugin/) like this:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <mainClass>com.my.mainClass</mainClass>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>repackage</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Still its not working.. getting the same exception. Can there be any problem with dependencies?

Comment: See my modified answer with a defined main class.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so actually this was causing problem:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-oauth-client-jetty</artifactId>
      <version>1.24.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

as in the dependency hierarchy, I saw version of servlet-api was < 3.1 and so it was overriding the version.

Hence solved it by excluding it:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-oauth-client-jetty</artifactId>
      <version>1.24.1</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Refer following for more information:
[Question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19078023/how-to-make-a-maven-sub-dependency-provided-in-3rd-party-dependency)
[Question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34950164/getting-nosuchmethoderrorjavax-servlet-servletcontext-getvirtualservername)